# codeigniter: how do you declare sendsms( '919918xxxxxx', 'test message from spring edge' );

Tags: codeigniter, sms

sendsms( '919918xxxxxx', 'test message from spring edge' ); how do you declare this function in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter have a good functionality Helpers. Helper functions are available in all controllers(if auto-load). You can use codeigniter helper to declare this function.

Open a file in Application/Heplers/sendsms_helper.php

```
 /*Start sendsms_helper.php file */

    function sendsms($number, $message_body, $return = '0'){       
        $sender = 'SEDEMO';  //Use sender name here
        $smsGatewayUrl = 'SMS_GATEWAY_URL_HERE';
        $apikey = '62q3z3hs49xxxxxx'; // Use API key here

        $textmessage = urlencode($textmessage);
        $api_element = '/api/web/send/';
        $api_params = $api_element.'?apikey='.$apikey.'&sender='.$sender.'&to='.$mobileno.
'&message='.$textmessage;    
        $smsgatewaydata = $smsGatewayUrl.$api_params;
        $url = $smsgatewaydata;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if($return == '1'){
            return $output;            
        }
    }

/*     * End sendsms_helper.php file     */
```

**How to use in controller:**

- Load sendsms helper in controller using $this->load->helper('sendsms_helper');
- Call sendsms function Ex. sendsms( '919918xxxxxx', 'test message from spring edge' );

Comment: Thanks but I already done that. My concern is how you would call the function sendsms() like do you call it in the helper file too or in the controller file?

Comment: In controller : first load helper in controller by $this->load->helper('sendsms_helper');

Than: write sendsms( '919918xxxxxx', 'test message from spring edge' ); in controller to call function.

I have modified foot-note of answer accordingly .